# SpotFire - Sum up values over multiple Columns

Tags: spotfire

I need to sum the Net_Amount column in my table over 3 different columns those columns being:

- UWI
- Year
- Month

How do I go about doing this? Please note I would like to do this through the data canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FikJq.png)

I tried doing Sum___ Over Data transformation but I cannot seem to make it work for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you need to sum [Net_Amount] for every distinct combination of UWI, Year and Month?
In that case you would define the new sum column with this expression:

```
sum([Net_Amount]) over intersect([UWI],[Year],[Month])
```

You can add a calculated column via the data canvas as well as outside of it.